# How to draw a line wpf

Tags: wpf

```
public void CreateALine()
{
    // Create a Line
    Line redLine = new Line();
    redLine.X1 = 50;
    redLine.Y1 = 50;
    redLine.X2 = 200;
    redLine.Y2 = 200;

    // Create a red Brush
    SolidColorBrush redBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
    redBrush.Color = Colors.Red;

    // Set Line's width and color
    redLine.StrokeThickness = 4;
    redLine.Stroke = redBrush;

    // Add line to the Grid.
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(redLine);
}
```

I have code from [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/line-in-wpf/)
I need to draw line.
But there is some object LayoutRoot in tutorial which  is not definedin my code what should i do?

Comment: Layout root is just an element name that was probably added in the XAML markup. In WPF you can access those directly. Go to your XAML file and make a grid and add the Name LayoutRoot to it, alternatively use a different name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It signifies a `panel name` in your XAML file. It can be `grid or any other panel type`.

```
<Window>
   <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    ....
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: `x` is a XAML syntax for giving name to any UI component. When you create WPF project, you can see this declaration at top of window - `xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" `.